# Number of flow files in HandleHttpRequest processor

Tags: apache-nifi

My HandleHttpRequest receives multiple files in a request. I need to process all these files and then only I need to send response. I looked at its source to extend it but there is no easy way as most of the methods are private.

I request a new attribute (something like flowfiles.count) to be added to the flow files so that a wait/sync mechanism can be implemented.

Or define a method in HttpContextMap to get the number of flowfiles which can be provided at the time of register.

Is there any solution that I can use for now?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear. multiple files - are they coming through one http request or through multiple requests?

Comment: in a single request

Answer (score 1):

starting from nifi 1.8.0 the feature exists.

from additional information of the [HandleHttpRequest 1.8.0 processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest/additionalDetails.html):

To handle requests with Content-Type: `multipart/form-data` containing multiple parts, additional attention needs to be paid. Each part generates a FlowFile of its own. To each these FlowFiles, some special attributes are written:

- `http.context.identifier`
- `http.multipart.fragments.sequence.number`
- `http.multipart.fragments.total.number`

These attributes could be used to implement a gating mechanism for HandleHttpResponse processor to wait for the processing of FlowFiles with sequence number `http.multipart.fragments.sequence.number` until up to `http.multipart.fragments.total.number` of flow files are processed, belonging to the same `http.context.identifier`, which is unique to the request.